# How to boost specific fields in django-elasticsearch-dsl document definition?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl-py, django-elasticsearch-dsl

I would like to automatically boost fields (title, in this case) in all searches in this index.  Is this possible?

```
@registry.register_document
class GuideDocument(Document):
    title = fields.TextField(attr="__str__")
    content = fields.TextField(attr="get_content")
    url = fields.TextField(attr="get_absolute_url")

    class Index:
        name = "guides"

    class Django:
        model = Guide

        fields = [
            "id",
            "description",
        ]
```